Powershell - Create new user accounts from CSV & simultaneously populate these new accounts with template account info (Address & group membership)
I can create user accounts with a CSV ok in Powershell.

I can also create an account from a template account in Powershell, and the info like address & group memberships comes across ok.
However, when trying to combine both operations inside of a foreach loop, the additional info from the template account will not populate into the new accounts created from the CSV.
I tried using variables to capture the Template User properties, to include using a variable to capture only the group info from the template account.
I also tried using specific names for the accounts instead of variables.  However, the data from the template account does not go over to the accounts created from CSV in the foreach loop.
You can see in the below images, that the data never populates in the newly created users. (I don't know why the images aren't showing, it showed me a thumbnail & gave me option to "Add Image")





You can see in the following code the things that I have tried:
#------------------------- Create users with CSV & Template -------------------------------
# Goal = to get all settings from template account  to include city, address, & groups 
#   into each account that is being created from the CSV.
#      The accounts create, but the other data (address & groups) do not populate.

# Import the CSV file
$users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Posh_Server2022\AD\Users.csv"

   # Get the template user 
$templateUser = Get-ADUser -Identity "Template User"

# Loop through each user in the CSV file
foreach ($user_ in $users) {
    # Create the new user based on the template
     New-ADUser  -Name $user_.Name `
    -GivenName $user_.GivenName `
    -Surname $user_.Surname `
    -SamAccountName $user_.UserName `
    -AccountPassword $user_.Password `
    -Instance $templateUser

# Get the groups that the template user is a member of
#$groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $templateUser

############## THIS IS WHERE PROBLEMS START ##############
    #$tmpltUsr = Get-ADUser 'Template User' -Properties MemberOf
       #$tmpltUsr = Get-ADUser 'Template User' # THIS GIVES NO ERRORS BUT DOESN'T WORK
     #$tmpltUsr = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity "Template User"
            #ForEach($group in 'Template User'.MemberOf){
               # ForEach($group in $groups){
               ForEach($group in $templateUser.MemberOf){ # THIS GIVES NO ERRORS BUT DOESN'T WORK
                   # ForEach($group in $templateUser){
              Add-ADGroupMember $group -Members $user_ #THIS GAVE NO ERRORS
            #Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.Name -Members $user_
    }
}

###################################################
CSV:
Name,GivenName,Surname,UserName,AccountPassword
Test User1,Test,User1,tuser1,Password
Test User2,Test,User2,tuser2,Password

I would use New-ADUser ... -PassThru for this, see: Adding user to group after running New-ADUser.

@iRon - Thanks.  I am currently out of town and will look at that upon my return Friday evening.

Unfortunately, I am still unable to make this work.  Always errors or looks like it goes through, but nothing happens.

@Theo - Running your script the way it is, $newusers comes up null when trying to add groups.

@iRon - piping to Foreach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Template User" -Members $_} causes it to just kind of sit there and never falls through.

Gentlemen, I have groups from template account going over to newly created accounts.  Working on getting those properties over now.

Got it.  Thanks @iRon & @Theo!

As iRon commented, you do not capture the object created by New-ADUser and your code now uses a  PsCustomObject read from the CSV as value for parameter -Members, but that will not work.
Acceptable values for that can be found here
Also, I recommend not using those horrible backticks, but instead use Splatting on cmdlets that can take a lot of parameters.
Try
#------------------------- Create users with CSV & Template -------------------------------

# Import the CSV file
$csvUsers = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Posh_Server2022\AD\Users.csv"

# Get the template user (your code shows the Name only, not the SamAccountName which would be a lot easier)

# Get-ADUser by default returns these properties:
# DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
# If you need extra user properties, you must provide them in parameter `Properties

$propsToCopy  = 'StreetAddress', 'City', 'State', 'PostalCode', 'POBox'
$templateUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq 'Template User' -or DisplayName -eq 'Template User'" -Properties MemberOf, $propsToCopy
if (!$templateUser) {
    throw "Cannot find the template user.."
}

# Loop through each user in the CSV file and collect the user objects in $newUsers
$newUsers = foreach ($user in $csvUsers) {
    # Create the new user based on the template
    $userParams = @{
        Name            = $user.Name
        GivenName       = $user.GivenName
        Surname         = $user.Surname
        SamAccountName  = $user.UserName
        AccountPassword = $user.Password
        Instance        = $templateUser
        Enabled         = $true
        PassThru        = $true  # this makes the New-ADUser cmdlet output the ADPrincipal object it created
    }

    New-ADUser @userParams
}

# add the new users to the groups the Template User is a member of
foreach ($groupDN in $templateUser.MemberOf) {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupDN -Members $newUsers
}

